# Valgrind... 4 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm getting this error in Valgrind after attempting to free a list.  print_list dumps the list to the syslog.  I'm pretty confident that output is correct.

Valgrind:

```
==7028== 1 errors in context 1 of 10:
==7028== Invalid read of size 4
==7028==    at 0x8049603: free_list (list.c:239)
==7028==    by 0x80488B5: m61_close_for_valgrind (m61.c:36)
==7028==    by 0x8048825: main (mytest.c:19)
==7028==  Address 0x420006c is 4 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==7028==    at 0x4028F0F: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==7028==    by 0x804960C: free_list (list.c:239)
==7028==    by 0x80488B5: m61_close_for_valgrind (m61.c:36)
==7028==    by 0x8048825: main (mytest.c:19)
==7028==
```

mytest.c:

```
15  char *temp = malloc(10);
16  char *temp2 = malloc(10);
17  free(temp);
18  free(temp2);
19  m61_close_for_valgrind();
```

list.h

```
typedef struct lnode {
    ACTIVE_ALLOCATION *value;
    struct lnode *next;
} lnode;
```

list.c (Called by m61_close_for_valgrind()

```
void free_list(LIST *s) {

    lnode **nptr = &s->head;

    print_list(s);
    while (*nptr) {
        lnode **tmp = nptr;
        tmp = nptr;

        if ((*tmp)->value) {
            syslog(LOG_NOTICE,"Freeing (*tmp)->value=%p\n", (*tmp)->value);
            //printf("%p\n",(*nptr)->value);
            free((*tmp)->value);    //Free active allocation metadata
        }

        nptr = &(*nptr)->next;
        syslog(LOG_NOTICE,"New *nptr value=%p\n", (*nptr));

        syslog(LOG_NOTICE,"Freeing (*tmp)=%p\n", (*tmp));
        free(*tmp);             //Free node

    }

}
```

syslog

```
Sep 19 00:37:02 appliance mytest[7759]:   -- Start List Dump --
Sep 19 00:37:02 appliance mytest[7759]:   (*nptr)=0x903f220 (*nptr)->value=0x903f208   (*nptr)->next=0x903f260  (*nptr)->value->ptr=0x903f1f0
Sep 19 00:37:02 appliance mytest[7759]: (*nptr)->value->ptr=0x903f1f0
Sep 19 00:37:02 appliance mytest[7759]:   (*nptr)=0x903f260 (*nptr)->value=0x903f248   (*nptr)->next=(nil)  (*nptr)->value->ptr=0x903f230
Sep 19 00:37:02 appliance mytest[7759]: (*nptr)->value->ptr=0x903f230
Sep 19 00:37:02 appliance mytest[7759]:   -- End List Dump --
Sep 19 00:37:02 appliance mytest[7759]: Freeing (*tmp)->value=0x903f208
Sep 19 00:37:02 appliance mytest[7759]: New *nptr value=0x903f260
Sep 19 00:37:02 appliance mytest[7759]: Freeing (*tmp)=0x903f220
Sep 19 00:37:02 appliance mytest[7759]: Freeing (*tmp)->value=0x903f248
Sep 19 00:37:02 appliance mytest[7759]: New *nptr value=(nil)
Sep 19 00:37:02 appliance mytest[7759]: Freeing (*tmp)=0x903f260
```

Comment: I'm puzzled; the `valgrind` report refers to an address 0x0420006C, but your trace via `syslog()` does not refer to any address anywhere near that.  Did you change the code after you generated the report but before you generated the trace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As caf already wrote, you're accessing memory that has just been freed.

To fix that, just don't use double pointers, single pointers will do very well here.

So replace

```
lnode **nptr = &s->head;
```

by

```
lnode *nptr = s->head;
```

Same for

```
lnode **tmp = nptr;
```

in the loop. Make it

```
lnode *tmp = nptr;
```

and while you're at it, drop the double assignment.

Then access `value` and `next` by

```
tmp->value
```

and

```
tmp->next
```

directly.

Answer (score 7):

In each iteration other than the first, `tmp` points at the `next` pointer from the previous node - but you've already freed that node (in the previous iteration), so `tmp` points into a freed block and you can't dereference it.