# Segmentation fault while calling gsl_integration

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gsl

I am trying to implement the multidimensional integration routine from Numerical Recipes (code taken from [here](http://pqcd.elte.hu/~pg/numrec/c4-6.pdf), pg. 164). The use of wrappers to pass the integrand to `void* params` is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593726/a-function-pointer-issue-how-to-efficiently-interface-with-c-api-ie-gsl-from) (further references there). My `class` declarations are in `NRquad3d_Const_qags_2.C` as follows

```
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>

gsl_integration_workspace * w1 = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (100000);
gsl_integration_workspace * w2 = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (100000);

double func3d(double x, double y, double z);

class NRf3 {
public:
  double xsav, ysav;

  double ret_int(double z)
  {  
    return func3d(xsav, ysav, z);
  }

  static double ret_int_wrapper(double z, void *params)
  {
   return static_cast<NRf3*>(params)->ret_int(z); 
  }

};

//integrates over the z-variable
class NRf2 {
private:
  double z1, z2;
  gsl_function F2; 

public:
  NRf3 f3;
  double resultf2, errorf2;

  NRf2 (double zz1, double zz2): z1(zz1), z2(zz2) {}

  double ret_int_2(double y) 
  {
    f3.ysav = y;        

    F2.function = &(f3.ret_int_wrapper);
    F2.params = &f3;

    gsl_integration_qags(&F2, z1, z2, 0, 1e-7, 10, w1, &resultf2, &errorf2);
    gsl_integration_workspace_free (w1);

    return resultf2; 
    }

  static double ret_int_2_wrapper(double y, void *params)
  {
   return static_cast<NRf2*>(params)->ret_int_2(y); 
  }

};
//integrates over the y-variable ==> gives function of x

class output {
private:  
  gsl_function F;
public:
  double result, error;

  double integrate(double x, double y1, double y2, double z1, double z2){

    NRf2 f2(z1, z2);
    f2.f3.xsav = x;

    F.function = &(f2.ret_int_2_wrapper);
    F.params = &f2;

    gsl_integration_qags(&F, y1, y2, 0, 1e-7, 10, w2, &result, &error);
    gsl_integration_workspace_free (w2);

    return result;
  }

};
```

And i call the integrator as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include </users/.../NRquad3d_Const_qags_2.C>

double func3d(double x, double y, double z)
  {
    double f = x*y*z;
    return f;
  }


int main (void)
{
  double result; 
  double error;
  double expected = -4.0;

  output out ; 
  result = out.integrate(1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

  printf ("result          = % .18f\n", result);
  printf ("exact result    = % .18f\n", expected); 
  printf ("actual error    = % .18f\n", result - expected);

  return 0;
}
```

Code compiles ok, but running `a.out` gives me a segfault. Backtrace from `gdb` gives

```
#0  0x00007ffff7a4b430 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libgsl.so.0
#1  0x0000000000400bed in NRf2::ret_int_2 (this=0x7fffffffdbd0, y=-0.97390652851717174) at /users/.../NRquad3d_Const_qags_2.C:45
#2  0x0000000000400c39 in NRf2::ret_int_2_wrapper (y=-0.97390652851717174, params=0x7fffffffdbd0) at /users/.../NRquad3d_Const_qags_2.C:53
#3  0x00007ffff7a49c6e in gsl_integration_qk () from /usr/lib64/libgsl.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff7a4997b in gsl_integration_qk21 () from /usr/lib64/libgsl.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff7a4b4c7 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libgsl.so.0
#6  0x0000000000400d14 in output::integrate (this=0x7fffffffdc30, x=1, y1=-1, y2=1, z1=-1, z2=1) at /users/.../NRquad3d_Const_qags_2.C:73
#7  0x00000000004009ac in main () at crap_test.cpp:22
(gdb) frame 6
#6  0x0000000000400d14 in output::integrate (this=0x7fffffffdc30, x=1, y1=-1, y2=1, z1=-1, z2=1) at /users/.../NRquad3d_Const_qags_2.C:73
73          gsl_integration_qags(&F, y1, y2, 0, 1e-7, 10, w2, &result, &error);
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x0000000000400bed in NRf2::ret_int_2 (this=0x7fffffffdbd0, y=-0.97390652851717174) at /users/.../NRquad3d_Const_qags_2.C:45
45          gsl_integration_qags(&F2, z1, z2, 0, 1e-7, 10, w1, &resultf2, &errorf2);
```

Running `gdb` already helped me eliminate a clash in the addresses of `w1` and `w2`, but the segfault still remains. Since the error seems to occur in the call in the second call to `qags` in `NRf2` i think there must be a deallocated pointer i am trying to refer to, but i can't seem to find it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `valgrind` gives errors of the form:

```
==26286== Invalid read of size 8
==26286==    at 0x4ED0239: gsl_integration_workspace_free (in /usr/lib64/libgsl.so.0.16.0)
==26286==    by 0x400A54: main (crap_test.cpp:32)
==26286==  Address 0x6053090 is 80 bytes inside a block of size 88 free'd
==26286==    at 0x4C29D4E: free (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26286==    by 0x400C39: NRf2::ret_int_2(double) (NRquad3d_Const_qags_2.C:46)
==26286==    by 0x400C76: NRf2::ret_int_2_wrapper(double, void*) (NRquad3d_Const_qags_2.C:53)
==26286==    by 0x4ECBBA3: gsl_integration_qk (in /usr/lib64/libgsl.so.0.16.0)
==26286==    by 0x4ECB97A: gsl_integration_qk21 (in /usr/lib64/libgsl.so.0.16.0)
==26286==    by 0x4ECD4C6: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgsl.so.0.16.0)
==26286==    by 0x400D51: output::integrate(double, double, double, double, double) (NRquad3d_Const_qags_2.C:73)
==26286==    by 0x4009CB: main (crap_test.cpp:25)
```

which hints at me [trying to access freed memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886298/valgrind-4-bytes-inside-a-block-of-size-8-freed). The only places in my script where i try to do this are at the lines

```
gsl_integration_workspace_free (w1);
.
.
.
.
gsl_integration_workspace_free (w2);
```

in the `.C` file. I then (re)move these lines to the end of my `.cpp` file and it works.

Silly error, but i'm going to answer this anyway in case someone has this exact (or similar!) error and needs a solution.

Comment: If you are really into C++, use unique_ptr with custom destructor to not have this problem anymore!